# How Drag over button

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm making an image & label widget with qToolButton and QRubberBand, but the dragging works well in the window, but the dragging doesn't work on the button. Is there a solution?

```
# coding:utf-8
from PySide2 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets

class QToolButton(QtWidgets.QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, label='', icon=''):
        super(QToolButton, self).__init__()
        self.label = label
        self.icon = icon
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        self.setText(self.label)
        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.icon))
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.rubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.resize(500, 300)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        for i in range(5):
            layout.addWidget(QToolButton(label='test', icon='test.jpg'))

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Flow Layout")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.origin = event.pos()
        self.rubberBand.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(self.origin, QtCore.QSize()))
        self.rubberBand.show()
        QtWidgets.QWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(
                QtCore.QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
        QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.rubberBand.hide()
            selected = []
            rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
            for child in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QToolButton):
                if rect.intersects(child.geometry()):
                    selected.append(child)
            if selected:
                for i in selected:
                    if i.isChecked():
                        i.setChecked(False)
                    else:
                        i.setChecked(True)
        QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

I'm making an image & label widget with qToolButton and QRubberBand, but the dragging works well in the window, but the dragging doesn't work on the button. Is there a solution?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: That looks like it is working,  what is the problem?

Comment: not working on button

Comment: @거북이냥 Do you mean that you want to be able to start the drag also when the mouse is over the button? If that's the case, there would be some important usability problems, as it would prevent normal usage of a button (which allows to *avoid* the click by moving the mouse outside it and then release the mouse button). Are you really sure you want it that way?

Comment: @musicamante yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

You must install an event filter on all widgets on which you want to provide that feature, and possibly use common functions for the rubber band to avoid repeated code.

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.rubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.resize(500, 300)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        for i in range(5):
            button = QToolButton(label='test', icon='test.jpg')
            layout.addWidget(button)
            button.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Flow Layout")

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
            self.origin = source.mapTo(self, event.pos())
        elif event.type() == event.MouseMove and event.buttons():
            if not self.rubberBand.isVisible():
                distance = (source.mapTo(self, event.pos()) - self.origin).manhattanLength()
                if distance > QtWidgets.QApplication.startDragDistance():
                    if isinstance(source, QtWidgets.QAbstractButton) and source.isDown():
                        source.setDown(False)
                    self.rubberBand.show()
            if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
                self.resizeRubberBand(source.mapTo(self, event.pos()))
                event.accept()
                return True
        elif event.type() == event.MouseButtonRelease and self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.closeRubberBand()
            event.accept()
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def startRubberBand(self, pos):
        self.origin = pos
        self.rubberBand.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(self.origin, QtCore.QSize()))
        self.rubberBand.show()

    def resizeRubberBand(self, pos):
        if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(
                QtCore.QRect(self.origin, pos).normalized())

    def closeRubberBand(self):
        if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.rubberBand.hide()
            selected = []
            rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
            for child in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QToolButton):
                if rect.intersects(child.geometry()):
                    selected.append(child)
            if selected:
                for i in selected:
                    if i.isChecked():
                        i.setChecked(False)
                    else:
                        i.setChecked(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.startRubberBand(event.pos())
        QtWidgets.QWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.resizeRubberBand(event.pos())
        QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.closeRubberBand()
        QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
```

Note that you should probably create, resize and close the rubberband by checking that all three mouse events are generated by the left button; in that case, remember that for mouseMoveEvent you should use `buttons()`, not `button()`.

Comment: That's great!!! that's what I want. You're the best teacher